# Wrong JavaScript algorithm in Map rendering with Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, canvas, 2d

So right now I have some simple code for creating a Map with a couple of tiles which is random generated, code:

```
function generateMap() {
    for (var y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
       for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
           this.map[x + y * this.width] = Math.round(Math.random() * (this.tileset.length - 1));
       }
    }

    this.map[this.width * this.height] = Math.round(Math.random() * (this.tileset.length - 1));
}
```

And here is the code for drawing the map (it uses 3 parameters, xOffset, yOffset, and Canvas 2dcontext object):

```
function renderMap(xOff, yOff, g) {
    var wPort = Math.ceil(WIDTH/64);
    var hPort = Math.ceil(HEIGHT/64);
    var xx = 0;
    var yy = 0;

    for (var y = this.yTile; y < this.yTile+hPort+2; y++) {
        xx = 0;
        for (var x = this.xTile; x < this.xTile+wPort+2; x++) {
            var fTile = x + y * this.width;

            if (fTile > this.width*this.height || fTile < 0 || x < 0 || x > this.width || y < 0 || y > this.height) {
                this.overheaptile.render(xOff + this.xOff + xx * 64 - 128, yOff + this.yOff + yy * 64 - 128, g);
            } else {
                this.tileset[ this.map[fTile] ].render(xOff + this.xOff + xx * 64 - 128, yOff + this.yOff + yy * 64 - 128, g);
            }

            if (debug) {
                g.fillText(fTile, xOff + this.xOff + xx * 64 - 100, yOff + this.yOff + yy * 64 - 94);
                g.strokeRect(xOff + this.xOff + xx * 64 - 128, yOff + this.yOff + yy * 64 - 128, 64, 64);
            }

            xx++;
        }
        yy++;
    }
}
```

My problem can be explained by using this picture:

[image: Problem]

As you're able to see, everytime a new yy starts it uses the previous tile which makes the map scrambled up, how can I fix this?

COMPLETE MAP JS FILE: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48864953/map.js

Comment: The code is very hard to understand because of strange logic. I would recommend using a 2d array. myArray[x][y] = value; Then have a nested loop for a 10 x by 10 y map (I think you want a 10 by 10 map?) and fill each myArray[x][y] with a random tile. Then when you want to display the map, again do a nested loop to iterate through the array and use the x and y values multiplied by tile width & height to place the tiles in the correct position.

Comment: I fixed it and it's completely working, thank you! If you could reply this as an answer I will mark it as 'answered my question'.

Comment: Great, nice that you got it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a 2d array. Used like this: myArray[x][y] = value; Then have a nested loop for a 10 x by 10 y map (I think you want a 10 by 10 map?) and fill each myArray[x][y] with a random tile. Then when you want to display the map, again do a nested loop to iterate through the array and use the x and y values multiplied by tile width & height to place the tiles in the correct position.